# mypy: function definition in isinstance-condition: why is the type in the condition not narrowed down?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm defining functions inside a condition based on a variables type, a Union of other types. mypy infers that the type is narrowed down in this context, but seems to throw this knowledge away.

I don't understand why. Is this a bug in mypy?

Consider this:

```
from typing import Union, Callable

def test(a: Union[None, Callable]):
    if a is None:
        pass
    else:
        def test0():
            a()
        def test1(b: str):
            a(b)
        callable_a = a
        def test2(b: str):
            callable_a(b)
        a()
        a('foo')
```

mypy's output:

```
test.py:9: error: "None" not callable

Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

line 9 is the body of test1. Seems that here the whole `Union[None, Callable]` is applied
("the whole union" is not clear from this example, in the actual code it's Union[None, Sequence, Callable] and mypy objects that both None and Sequence are not callable).

outside function definitions, the problem does not appear.

Some thoughts:

- `callable_a` can only ever be a callable, so I'm a bit more willing to accept that mypy doesn't complain about this. I don't understand why it's complaining anyway.
- both `test0` and `test1` call `a`, the difference is only the argument. Why does this make a difference to mypy, especially here when the signature of `a` is undefined?

I'm running mypy 0.950 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behavior which is well explained in the [`mypy` docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#narrowing-and-inner-functions). Inference of `a` would be simply wrong because of late binding.

Here's the example given in the docs:

```py
from typing import Callable, Optional

def foo(x: Optional[int]) -> Callable[[], int]:
    if x is None:
        x = 5
    print(x + 1)  # mypy correctly deduces x must be an int here
    def inner() -> int:
        return x + 1  # but (correctly) complains about this line

    x = None  # because x could later be assigned None
    return inner

inner = foo(5)
inner()  # this will raise an error when called
```

Now about your code: First, functions without annotations are not checked, so you don't see all real errors. After adding type hints, we have the following:

```py
from typing import Union, Callable

def test(a: Union[None, Callable]):
    if a is None:
        pass
    else:
        def test0() -> None:
            a()  # E: "None" not callable
            
        def test1(b: str) -> None:
            a(b)  # E: "None" not callable
        
        callable_a = a
        reveal_type(callable_a)  # N: Revealed type is "def (*Any, **Any) -> Any"
        def test2(b: str) -> None:
            callable_a(b)
        
        a()
        a('foo')
```

Now only `test2` is valid, which is expected (see revealed type). `callable_a` is inferred to be `Callable` **only** from `is None` type guard, so you cannot assign `None` to it later. You can fix this with `assert callable(a)` inside `test0` and `test1` (dirty way) or use the same pattern as with `test2`. Default argument binding (using `def test0(a: Callable = a)` should be valid too but `mypy` doesn't like it for some reason - it is a false positive, but probably too hard to deal with or devs don't have time for it now.

Look through [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2608) if you are interested in `mypy`'s opinion on that.  Here's [a playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=c67cb3d56a8e4bb2a718e6b346e0e7ba) to play with this online.

Comment: right, thanks for your great answer! late binding came to my mind, but I didn't really see what it would do. I should've have checked the mypy documentation, only checked the peps and SO.